# Testing async YouTube API calls using Jasmine 2.0

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, youtube, jasmine

I'm upgrading my project from YouTube's V2 API to their V3 API. I'm also taking the time to upgrade to Jasmine 2.0 since I already need to look at my test cases.

Here's a couple of test cases and the corresponding code. Am I doing 'it' correctly?  Maybe I should have a spy?

```
define([
    'common/model/youTubeV3API'
], function (YouTubeV3API) {
    'use strict';

    describe('YouTubeV3API', function () {

        describe('when asked to find a playable song by title', function () {
            beforeEach(function (done) {

                this.result = null;

                YouTubeV3API.findPlayableByTitle({
                    title: 'Gramatik',
                    success: function (response) {
                        this.result = response;
                        done();
                    }.bind(this)
                });
            });

            it('should return a playable result', function() {
                expect(this.result).not.toBeNull();
            });

        });

        describe('when asked to search for songs', function () {

            beforeEach(function (done) {

                this.result = null;

                YouTubeV3API.search({
                    text: 'Gramatik',
                    success: function (response) {
                        this.result = response;
                        done();
                    }.bind(this)
                });
            });

            it('should return 50 songs', function () {
                expect(this.result.length).toEqual(50);
            });

        });
    }
}

define([
    'common/model/utility',
    'common/googleAPI'
], function (Utility, GoogleAPI) {
    'use strict';

    var YouTubeV3API = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults: {
            loaded: false
        },

        initialize: function () {
            GoogleAPI.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function () {
                this.set('loaded', true);
            }.bind(this));
        },

        //  Performs a search and then grabs the first item most related to the search title by calculating
        //  the levenshtein distance between all the possibilities and returning the result with the lowest distance.
        //  Expects options: { title: string, success: function, error: function }
        findPlayableByTitle: function (options) {
            return this.search({
                text: title,
                success: function (songInformationList) {

                    songInformationList.sort(function (a, b) {
                        return Utility.getLevenshteinDistance(a.title, title) - Utility.getLevenshteinDistance(b.title, title);
                    });

                    var songInformation = songInformationList.length > 0 ? songInformationList[0] : null;
                    options.success(songInformation);
                },
                error: options.error,
                complete: options.complete
            });
        },

        //  Performs a search of YouTube with the provided text and returns a list of playable songs (<= max-results)
        //  Expects options: { maxResults: integer, text: string, fields: string, success: function, error: function }
        search: function (options) {
            //  If the API has not loaded yet  - defer calling this event until ready.
            if (!this.get('loaded')) {
                this.once('change:loaded', function () {
                    this.search(options);
                });
                return;
            }

            var searchListRequest = GoogleAPI.client.youtube.search.list({
                part: 'id',
                //  Probably set this to its default of video/playlist/channel at some point.
                type: 'video',
                maxResults: options.maxResults || 50,
                q: options.text,
                //  I don't think it's a good idea to filter out results based on safeSearch for music.
                safeSearch: 'none'
            });

            searchListRequest.execute(function (response) {
                if (response.error) {
                    if (options.error) {
                        options.error({
                            error: response.error
                        });
                    }

                    if (options.complete) {
                        options.complete();
                    }
                } else {
                    var songIds = _.map(response.items, function (item) {
                        return item.id.videoId;
                    });

                    this._getSongInformationList(songIds, function (songInformationList) {
                        options.success(songInformationList);

                        if (options.complete) {
                            options.complete();
                        }
                    });
                }

            }.bind(this));

        },
        //  Converts a list of YouTube song ids into actual video information by querying YouTube with the list of ids.
        _getSongInformationList: function(songIds, callback) {
            //  Now I need to take these songIds and get their information.
            var songsListRequest = GoogleAPI.client.youtube.videos.list({
                part: 'contentDetails,snippet',
                maxResults: 50,
                id: songIds.join(',')
            });

            songsListRequest.execute(function (response) {

                var songInformationList = _.map(response.items, function (item) {

                    return {
                        id: item.id,
                        duration: Utility.iso8061DurationToSeconds(item.contentDetails.duration),
                        title: item.snippet.title,
                        author: item.snippet.channelTitle
                    };

                });

                callback(songInformationList);
            });
        }
    });

    return new YouTubeV3API();
});
```

My main concerns are:

- I'm really interested in knowing I am calling YouTube's API properly, but I think it's best practice to stub out the calls to YouTube and mock responses. Is that true?
- I'm not using a Spy to check success value, but, again, seems a bit awkward to actually use it in my scenario... Would love an example.
- Jasmine 2.0 syntax reads nicer, but seems a bit less generous with asynchronous calls. Have I structured things properly by placing code in a beforeEach, but only have one "it" call? I don't think I want to hammer YouTube's API many times for each "it" following a "beforeEach" ... so it seems odd to have it there. This problem would go away with stubbing my calls to YouTube though..

Answer (score 1):

This looks okay to me, the only thing I will comment on is this:

```
            if (response.error) {
                if (options.error) {
                    options.error({
                        error: response.error
                    });
                }

                if (options.complete) {
                    options.complete();
                }
            }
```

If you default `.complete()` and `.error()` like this:

```
    var doNothing = function(){};
    options.complete = options.complete || doNothing();
    options.error = options.error || doNothing();
```

then that first block would be simply

```
            if (response.error) {
                options.error({ error: response.error });
                options.complete();
            }
```